# In Stanford iOS development course lecture 1 calculator demo, how does the variable userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping work?

Tags: ios, swift

How does the variable, userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping, which is for getting rid of default 0 displayed when typing a new number, work? Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class Viewcontroller: UIViewController {

    IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false

    @IBAction func touchDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheModdleOfTyping {
            let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
            display.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + digit
        } else {
            display.text = digit
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true
    }
```

Comment: Er, yes? It is a variable. It helps detecting the initial (first) time the action is called versus following times it is called.

Comment: this was a rather stupid question... sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it because you need to know if the user is currently typing a number or not. If they are typing a number you need to append the number to the text currently in the display. If they are not in the middle of typing a number you set the display to the number they pressed.

As shown in your code, if the user is currently typing a number, you save the current text from the display in a temp variable, and set the text in the display to that variable and the digit the user pressed. If userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping is false, you just set the text in the display to the digit they pressed.

Lets say the user is not currently typing a number, so the display is showing "0". If you did not have this variable and the user pressed 4, the display would now show "04", which you do not want.